# How to fill a QTextBrowser with a single table in Qt?

Tags: html, css, qt, pyside

I have been wrestling with html and css in QTextBrowser for the past two days in PySide.

My intent is to create a TV monitor like screen to show main text in the center and some side information on the right hand side and possibly some error message at the bottom of the screen. I am not sure if table is the correct way to go by the way.

I want to know how to use html and css to get a table that spans 100% in both directions. I now have a problem with the height of table. According to the Qt doc [Supported HTML Subset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html#table-cell-attributes), `table` supports the following attributes: border, bgcolor (Qt color names or #RRGGBB), cellspacing, cellpadding, width (absolute or relative), and **height**.

However, when I specify height like this:
   `table{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%
   }` in css
or inline like this: `<table border="1" height:100%>`. Neither works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: My table currently look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using `QGridLayout`?

It has a lot of great functionality for filling up a space with the widgets in the right place.

You have a lot of control over the stretch, percentages, fixed, minimum, maximum, aspects of the sizes.

In each of the cells of the grid layout, you put the widget that you are planning on using.

For you, it sounds like most of them are going to be `QLabel`s.  If there is going to be some scrolling text, you could use `QTextEdit` or `QTextDocument` or `QTextBrowser`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am aware of QGridLayout. With QGridLayout, I have to predetermine what widgets must be there. The reason why I preferred QTextBrowser is more efficient use of the area. Say, I know that normal msgs and errors will not appear together so I could use the same space to display either one depending on the context.

Comment: You don't need to know what is going to be in your layout beforehand.  You can put 10 widgets in the same spot and hide most of them, and show the ones you want.  It really is powerful, but there is a learning curve to it.  It is common for most GUI libraries to use something like layouts.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html  It will take a few more minutes now to understand, but you will thank yourself later.

Comment: Probably I asked too much from the HTML and CSS functionalities from the TextBrowser. I will give up trying and use what you have suggested. Thanks a lot.